# Installing locally a jar in maven using cmd command

Tags: java, maven

I try to install a jar file locally in a maven project in netbeans using CMD command

According to this example:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
    -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
    -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

from [here](https://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/)

I run this command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\opt\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\myapplication\files\rrunner_jar\Ropt.jar \ -DgroupId=acaller -DartifactId=ACaller \ -Dversion=1.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

In the cd path `C:/Users/Alia`

but I receive this error

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I run it properly?

Comment: You need to add Maven to your classpath, q.v. [here](http://crunchify.com/how-to-setupinstall-maven-classpath-variable-on-windows-7/) or many other tutorials.  Windows right now does know what `mvn` means, so you have to tell it what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that windows can't find the mvn executable because it isn't on your path. Please make sure that maven is installed correctly. Here is a tutorial that includes a section about setting up your path for maven.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Add the M2_HOME in your environment variables. Since, your mvn command is unable to locate the M2_HOME, it is giving this error. This link will help you in doing it - https://maven.apache.org/install.html